# Leaflet Marker update

Tags: javascript, leaflet, angular-leaflet-directive

Hi I have a question about leaflet marker on angular 5 , 
the marker value is dynamic and I need to draw just the last result.
How can I do it please?
is here someone who had the same problem?

var markers; markers = new L.LayerGroup().addTo(myfrugalmap); let timer = TimerObservable.create(0, 10000); this.subscription = timer.subscribe(t => { this.MyService.Localize().subscribe( result => { this.positions = result; let xpo = this.positions.x; let ypo = this.positions.y; let mar=L.marker([xpo,ypo], {icon: greenIcon}) mar.addTo(markers) }); markers.clearLayers(); } )

in result (without (markers.clearLayers)) I have evry 10 second the new position on the map and I need to drop the old positions

Comment: Please provide more information and/or code samples. Show us what you've tried so far. It is difficult to identify the problem with what you've given.

Comment: var markers;
     markers = new L.LayerGroup().addTo(myfrugalmap);

    let timer = TimerObservable.create(0, 10000);
    
    this.subscription = timer.subscribe(t => {
      this.MyService.Localize().subscribe(
        result => {
          this.positions = result;
          let xpo = this.positions.x;
      let ypo = this.positions.y;
         
          let mar=L.marker([xpo,ypo], {icon: greenIcon})
         
         
          mar.addTo(markers)
            
          });
          
          markers.clearLayers();
       
        }
      )

Comment: in result (without (markers.clearLayers)) I have evry 10 second the new position on the map and I need to drop the old positions

Comment: nipuna777 what do you think ?

Comment: @YASSIRELHOUSNI Please don't post this in comment, edit your post.